# Does every div needs a set height?

Tags: html, css, height

I'm stressing out because of a mindbreaker and I'm probably missing some essential, but easy thing.. And although I've done this many times before.. it's going wrong now.

So I'm creating a web app and always my starting point is

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

And some of my inner elements have a set height in percentages and some in pixels.
However, to have some structure in my code, I'm setting up `div`'s without a set height. Let's set up the following situation.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thisIsAStructureItem">
    <div class="innerElement">
      And just some untagged piece of text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.thisIsAStructureItem {
/* nothing, not even height */
}

.innerElement {
  height: 17.5%;
}
```

But in any editor or browser, because I haven't set a specific (%/px) height on the second element, it shows up as 0px, including all the inner elements.

So stupid as this might be.. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nx0b7e7w/)

*The situation makes it appear a set height is necessary, therefor so my title. Feel free to adjust to something more suitable*

*The situation above is a replica of a to-build-situation and using exact pixels is (at that above part) not an option. Please don't advice 'use X pixels'.*

Comment: By default a block level element, like a div, will expand its height to fit its contents.

Comment: That was my thought too- and was the case in my past experience. Yet it's not working. Not in my situation, nor in your, just deleted, JSfiddle. (Just add a border to see the exact height)

Comment: What fiddle of mine are you referring to? And the fiddle you posted is quite different from what you posted in your question. Is this the behavior you're expecting http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ek6qwvs8/?

Comment: I was actually referring to Cory's JSfiddle. My JSfiddle is indeed different from in this post, but the situation is the same. .appContent is 100% height, .nieuwsModule isn't set and .FPNewsitem is 17.5%, but not getting any height because the second element (.nieuwsModule) hasn't a set height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Original**: http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lfyt0m
- **Updated**: http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lfyt0m/1/ (from code sample below)

The innerElement is trying to display as 17.5% as tall as the parent element. The problem is that the parent element does not have a defined height. As a fall back to calculating 17.5% of undefined, the div's height is essentially defaulting to "auto" and assuming the height of it's content, which is based on the size of the font, line-height, padding etc.

**Edit:** A nice feature of CSS is that an elements styles can be inherited from it's parents. You can add a structure class which will inhert the height from it's parent element, which seems to be your intent.

You could even add this class to the body element, since it's height and width are identical to html... just not certain if the HTML element can be styled in all browsers, so I didn't do that.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.struct {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.innerElement {
  height: 17.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="struct"> <!-- .struct inherits height/width from .wrapper -->
    <div class="innerElement"> <!-- height calculated based on .wrapper -->
      And just some untagged piece of text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great explanation. Quite that I thought, but I was hoping for a greater solution in the case of where I don't know the height of the child element(s).. Gladly there are, in my case, 5 items of percentages that I can add up and use as a height for the second element.

Comment: It sounds like you might be at the point in your CSS usage where you'd want to consider using a CSS preprocessor like SCSS/SASS. http://sass-lang.com/ Take a look at the operators http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-8

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to set the height 100% for that div too. Otherwise it's height is unknown and will not be able to take exactly the 100% height and innerElement height is not calculated accordingly.

To make sure, you must use the height 100% for that div too.

```
.wrapper {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.thisIsAStructureItem {
  height: 100%;
}

.innerElement {
  height: 17.5%;/* calc from it's parent div height i.e. thisIsAStructureItem*/
}
```

You are, in effect, asking the browser to calculate a height from an undefined value. Since that would equal a null-value, the result is that the browser does nothing.

Comment: From my point of view.. Isn't it more logical that every element inherits their parent attributes? Thus the set/remaining height of it's parent should be inherited and so the second (not set element) gets automaticly a height of 100%?

Comment: No, that's not exactly happen in percentage use.

Comment: Well, let's change the case a bit. I don't want the second element to be equal to 100% height, as that is too much, but I don't know the exact value either? The exact height should be equal to it's content?

Comment: Yes, the height depends on it's content, but not exactly, see last note of my answer.